# Gradient Descent calculation feature space with two features

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I try to calculate the optimal weights W[0] and W[1] for a linear regression of the the shape:

```
prize=W0*dummy+W1*size
```

where:

```
dummy=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
size=[500,550,620,630,665,700,770,880,920,1000]
```

the target feature (`rental_prize`) has the values:

```
rental_price=[320,380,400,390,385,410,480,600,570,620]
```

With the following code I try to calculate W0 and W1 such that the linear regression optimally fits the data.

```
# descriptive features
size=[500,550,620,630,665,700,770,880,920,1000]
dummy=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

# Vector which contains the descriptive features
features=[dummy,size]

# target feature
rental_price=[320,380,400,390,385,410,480,600,570,620]

# Set the learning rate alpha
alpha=0.002 

# Feature weight vector --> model=[W0,W1]
# Set initial values for W0 and W1
model=[0,0]

for i in range(len(model)):
    for j in range(100):
        errordelta=np.sum([(rental_price[x]-(model[0]*dummy[x]+model[1]*size[x]))*features[i][x] for x in range(len(size))])
        model[i]=model[i]+alpha*errordelta

print(model[0])
print(model[1])
```

> 395.09179229
>
> nan

The model should actually return about 6.47 for W0 and 0.62 for W1. If I change the values for alpha as well as for the inital weights and the iterations (j) the model still does not even come close to the desired values...

Obviously there must be a failure in the code....

Can anybode help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You have three errors in your algorithm:

- I don't know why you multiplied the absolute error by the value of the feature; this makes the error function quadratic, but you didn't compensate with any sqrt.
- Similarly, you failed to average the error amount before your weight adjustment; this effectively magnifies the changes by a factor equal to the number of training rows.
- Your loop order is inverted: you want to train the features in turn, one iteration each.  You did it by training the intercept `dummy` first, then trying to take that value as an absolute and training the slope `size` afterward.  You need to alternate them.

After updates (and a couple of textual improvements):

```
for j in range(100):
    for i in range(len(model)):
        errordelta  =  np.sum([(rental_price[x] -
                                 (model[0]*dummy[x] + model[1]*sqft[x])) 
                             for x in range(len(sqft))]) / len(sqft)
        print(model, errordelta)
        model[i]  =  model[i] + alpha*errordelta

print(" sqft coeff", model[0])
print("dummy coeff", model[1])
```

Output:

```
[0, 0] 455.5
[0.91100000000000003, 0] 454.589
[0.91100000000000003, 0.90917800000000015] -203.201283
[0.5045974339999999, 0.90917800000000015] -202.794880434
[0.5045974339999999, 0.50358823913200013] 90.649311554
[0.68589605710799573, 0.50358823913200013] 90.4680129309
...
[0.62996765105739105, 0.62870771575527662] -1.70530256582e-14
[0.62996765105739105, 0.62870771575527662] -1.70530256582e-14
 sqft coeff 0.629967651057
dummy coeff 0.628707715755
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is very very close. The only thing which is a little bit confusing for me is that the actual model should be about [6.47,0.62] do you have any explanation?

Comment: I have solved the problem on my own. Nevertheless, I will accept your answer as solution since your third suggestion gave me the critical hint. Thanks!!!!

Comment: It is critical that all weights get updated at once (simultaneously) since otherwise the model fails

Comment: Right -- although many models can handle the successive update and converge to the proper point.  You're welcome to edit my answer, or post one of your own and accept that, instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#descriptive features
size=[500,550,620,630,665,700,770,880,920,1000]
dummy=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

#Vector which contains the descriptive features
features=[dummy,size]


#target feature
rental_prize=[320,380,400,390,385,410,480,600,570,620]


#########Gradient decent Algorithm#############



#Set the learning rate alpha
alpha=0.00000002

#Feature weight vector --> model=[W0,W1]
#Set initail values for W0 and W1
model=[-0.146,0.185]


#Sum Squared Error
scatterSSE=[]



for j in range(100):

    #Squared Error
    SSE=np.sum([(rental_prize[x]-(model[0]*features[0][x]+model[1]*features[1][x]))**2 for x in range(len(rental_prize))])
    scatterSSE.append(SSE)

    for i in range(len(model)):       

        #Updating the weight factors w[i]
        errorDelta=np.sum([(rental_prize[x]-(model[0]*features[0][x]+model[1]*features[1][x]))*features[i][x] for x in range(len(rental_prize))])
        model[i]=model[i]+alpha*errorDelta





#Linear Equation after 100 itarations        
print("Linear Equation after 100 iterations:","HOUSE PRIZE={0}+{1}*SIZE".format(model[0],model[1]),sep="\n")




#########Plot the results######        

fig= plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(132)

#Plot the SSE 
y=list(range(1,101,1))
ax.scatter(y,scatterSSE)
ax.set_title("SSE")
ax.set_ylabel("SSE")
ax.set_xlabel("Iterations")


#Plot the linear regression
ax1.scatter(size,rental_prize)

X=list(np.linspace(min(size),max(size),100))
y=[model[0]+model[1]*x for x in X]
ax1.plot(X,y,"red")
ax1.set_title("Linear Regression")
ax1.set_ylabel("Prize")
ax1.set_xlabel("Size")




plt.show()
```

> Linear Equation after 100 iterations:
>
> HOUSE PRIZE=-0.145+0.629*SIZE

[image]